# Remove the First Value in a List that Meets a Criterion

Tags: haskell, recursion, tail-recursion

I'm trying to solve this problem. This function takes two parameters. The first is a function that returns a boolean value, and the second is a list of numbers. The function is supposed to remove the first value in the second parameter that returns true when run with the first parameter. 
There's a second function, which does the same thing, except it removes the last value that satisfies it, instead of the first.
I'm fairly certain I have the logic down, as I tested it in another language and it worked, my only problem is translating it into Haskell syntax. Here's what I have:

```
removeFirst :: (t -> Bool) -> [t] -> [t]
removeFirst p xs = []
removeFirst p xs
        |   p y = ys 
        |   otherwise = y:removeFirst p ys
        where
            y:ys = xs

removeLast :: (t -> Bool) -> [t] -> [t]
removeLast p xs = []
removeLast p xs = reverse ( removeFirst p ( reverse xs ) )
```

I ran:

```
removeFirst even [1..10]
```

But instead of getting [1,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10] as expected, I get [].
What am I doing wrong?

Comment: GHC should raise a warning about overlapping patterns if you compile your code with `-Wall`, pointing at the bug.

Comment: I did, but I was unsure of what exactly that it meant, but it still compiled.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
removeFirst p xs = []
```

This always returns the empty list and it matches all arguments. I think you mean this.

```
removeFirst _ [] = []
```

Comment: Thank you! That does work. Now I must do the same thing, removing the second value. I will try to get something going before asking for help on that one.

Answer (score 2):

Your first equation,

```
removeFirst p xs = []
```

says „Whatever my arguments are, just return []“, and the rest of the code is ignored.

You probably mean

```
removeFirst p [] = []
```

saying „When the list is already empty, return the empty list.“